# Using Expo's Google authentication integration vs react-native-google-signin

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm building my first React Native app and I want to have Google signin.

I first went down the path of trying to integrate the library [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin) - seemed like a promising library! But then very quickly I got mired in problems with my development environment and figuring out Expo development builds. I never quite got it working.

Then I tried [Expo's Google authentication integration](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google), and I've gotten that working, at least on web and iOS via Expo. It returns the logged-in user's Google access_token, which I think is all I'm needing (I currently don't need access to any other of the user's Google data).

My main question is: what are the drawbacks or limitations of using Expo's authentication option, or, why would I want to use the react-native-google-signin library despite its much greater added complexity? Is the Expo option going to break when I try to officially turn my app into a native iOS app?